# Finding images on screen

Tags: java, image, sikuli

I'm a rookie java learner. I'm trying to develop a bot (or trainer, whatever) for a simple mini-game, I need to analyze the screen for images and press the corresponding action. Therefore: -

I first tried to use sikuli ScreenRegion for this, but it didn't quite go as expected. What I tried was something like this: -

```
if(arrowSet.find(oneDown)!=null)
{
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    r.delay(20);
}
```

But it just jumped to the action, even if the condition was false. Is my application of ScreenRegion wrong in this situation? Or should I use something different than sikuli?

Comment: Apparently s.find returns Null if it can't find the image in the region defined, so your code "if(s.find(x))" is not valid java to begin with...

Comment: I can't help thinking you've bitten off quite a lot. But it depends on the circumstances - do the images you are trying to find appear on some set places, or can they be anywhere on the screen, scaled and rotated?

Comment: @AKDADEVIL: My code was just like you said.

Comment: @Humungus: Anywhere on the screen, no. Scaled and rotated, no.

Comment: Generally what I do, when writing bots alike these, is to first write a detector system, which detects the coordinates of given images. The system is to fold, first stage is to simply dump a lot of screenshots using the robot class, possibly providing info to the screenshots about the state of the game. Second stage is to analyze the images for occurrences of the images in question, something which can be done by brute force pixel comparison, which is slow truly, but this is something you do before actually developing the not, so I personally think it should just be simple and stupid.

Comment: Once you've done the above, you'll have a list of coordinates, which you should now analyze, and give corresponding names to. Once your done, you should design a java class to encapsulate this behaiver, and possibly have an interface along the lines of just checking whether or not the image is shown at the specific location. On top of this, build you bots general logic. This is the approach I've used for my poker bot. Hope it will help you out :)

Comment: @Skeen: This is off-topic, but it seemed like the only way to contact you. Can I chat with you on this? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

If using Java is not required and you work under Windows, you might consider using [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) - Python tool/library for UI automation. It allows operations on images.

For example, to find out whether an image exists on screen:

```
Image("arrow_screenshot1.png").exists() # returns True or False
```

To click on an image:

```
click(Image("arrow_screenshot1.png"))
```

To find out image coordinates/center:

```
Image("arrow_screenshot1.png").x # returns x-coordinate
Image("arrow_screenshot1.png").y # returns y-coordinate
Image("arrow_screenshot1.png").center # returns Point object
```

To wait until an image appears on the screen:

```
wait_until(Image("arrow_screenshot1.png").exists)
```

etc.

I think that using [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) you can quite easily achieve what you need!

*Disclaimer: I'm one of [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/)'s developers*

Comment: Nice idea, what if I have to press an arrow key if an image exists? Also, are there control statements?

Comment: Its even easier. You simply call _press(LEFT)_ or _press(UP)_ etc. depending on which arrow key you need to press. The full list of Automa's commands can be found at http://www.getautoma.com/docs.

Comment: Control statements like If? As this program cant do without them

Comment: Of course you can use control statements. [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) is just a Python library - you can use all the Python language structures (if-statements, while loops, etc.) and its libraries. The Automa commands are simply Python functions and Automa ships with the Python interpreter. Take a look at some advanced usage examples: http://www.getautoma.com/examples/addmefast-bot

Comment: I don't know much of Python (null, to be precise). But still, I'll try it. I see # if but where's end if?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, guys! Seems like the image recognition of sikuli is fuzzy. It wont work with `targetImage.setMinRank(1.00)` wont work, but when I tried running the program with `targetImage.setMinRank(0.99)`, it all worked fluidly. Thank you for you help.

Comment: What format was your target image?  If you saved it in a lossy format, a perfect match might be impossible.  (Sikuli bug is also possible, but I have used scripts that request a perfect match and worked.)